# Webpack dist folder not served

Tags: webpack

My webpack config file has a `publicPath` setting that points to the `dist` folder, but when I run

```
webpack-dev-server
```

The index.html from the project root is served. When I move `index.html` from the root to the `dist` folder, I just see a directory view in the browser.

My directory

```
index.html
src
  game.ts
dist
  bundle.js
```

How can I tell webpack that my index.html is also in the dist folder? Why would webpack even use anything outside of the dist folder...?

```
var path = require('path');
var pathToPhaser = path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/phaser/');
var phaser = path.join(pathToPhaser, 'dist/phaser.js');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/game.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader', exclude: '/node_modules/' },
      { test: /phaser\.js$/, loader: 'expose-loader?Phaser' },
      { test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/, use: [{loader: 'file-loader', options: {
              outputPath: 'images',
      } }]}
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8080,
    open: true
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    alias: {
      phaser: phaser
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  filename: 'bundle.js',
},

...

devServer: {
  contentBase: './dist',
  // no publicPath
}
```

Comment: Ah, but now the images can't be found anymore, because I can't go "up" from the dist folder to the src folder.

Comment: If you don't want images in the /dist folder how about serving ./ instead? Since webpack-dev-server doesn't produce any files just keeps them in memory. Then change that in production mode. Another alternative is to use https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin to copy the image files to /dist

Comment: I do want images in the dist folder, but haven't got that working either. The problem is that `import img from "myfile.png"` gives an error: `module not found`. regardless of the path. And then, webpack won't place the images in the `dist` folder. It seems a chicken-and-egg problem.

Comment: Another "hack" I found is to use `devServer: { historyApiFallback: { index: '/dist/index.html', } }` and remove both publicPath and contentBase

Comment: If you want to import the image like that I believe the path is relative to the file. For example if you have /src/index.js and want /src/img/img.png your would do `import img from './img/img.png'`

Comment: I thought so too but I just can't `import` an image, no matter what path I use.

Comment: Thank you so much. By looking at this code I realized why after using npm run build my server wasnt quite reading other files right. Thanks to this i was able to add devServer and fix my app tyty.